# Sending location to Firebase using Button in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm trying to send the user's current location to Firebase using Geofire and I don't know what is missing with the following code and where should I insert it on this activity? I'm planning to send the user's location to Firebase once Location Services has been activated. Are there other ways to achieve this? [image]

The activity:

```
    sendLocation = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    sendLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext())
                    .checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

            result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {

                    try {
                        LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        Toast.makeText(SendLocation.this, "GPS is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (ApiException e) {

                        switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                                try {
                                    ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException)e;
                                    resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(SendLocation.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;

                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                //Device does not have location
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });

    signOut = findViewById(R.id.signOut);
    signOut.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        goToMainActivity();
    });
}

private void goToMainActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(SendLocation.this, MainActivity.class));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {

        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Location");
                GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(reference.child("Location").child(phoneNum.getUid));
                geoFire.setLocation("location", new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude));
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is required to be turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want to what's missing in the following code in the photo I shared, I can't seem to locate where the location values are stored in the rest of the source code so I can send it to Realtime Database. If the above code is wrong, what should be the correct way?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to locate where the location values are stored"? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).